# Ubuntu Crashing on Install, Beating Head for 2 Days

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, crash, ubiquity

So, I've been trying to install Ubuntu for 2 days now. Each time, something goes wrong.

For 18.04, ubiquity crashes during the installation right after I enter the user information and a few packages start downloading. Screenshots of the error attached below.

Then I tried 16.04 which installed perfectly, but freezes after I type my username and password.

Next I tried Xubuntu, which did the exact same thing 16.04 did.

Finally, I tried Mint, which did the same exact thing that 18.04 was doing.

At this point I'm super frustrated, and hoping that someone here can help me out. I'm a complete noob to Linux. I know the basics and that's about it.

I am running an Alienware R3 laptop with an intel chipset, an i7 2.6 GHz, 64 gig OS with 32 G of RAM. I am dual booting with Windows 10. I created the partitions using Windows disk manager, and disabled quickboot and turned off secure boot. I am installing via a USB flash drive, and used etcher to flash the ISO to the drive.

[image]

Any help that anyone can give would be incredibly awesome. Thank you for taking the time to read this. =)

-Steve

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like it could be the USB. One time this happened to me it was because the USB kept overheating and failing when it was installing. Another time because the usb had faulty memory. This was a problem with the really small usbs, not the long stick ones. I would try a reliable USB first, then try [rufus](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) to burn the USB.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that wasn't the issue. I tried a long stick because I did notice the USB drive was getting pretty hot, and it still gave me the same error. I'm seriously beating my head against the wall here, it shouldn't be this problematic to install one of the biggest names in linux.